# How to display text vertically from bottom to top using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to display the given word vertically from bottom to top and each letter in the word must be one below the other. (just like the below image.) 
I would like to achieve above mentioned scenario using JavaScript.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: document.write = str.split('').join('<br/>)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Except `document.write` is a function to be called, not to be assigned to, which doesn’t matter anyway since you shouldn’t use `document.write` anyway.

Comment: @Xufox yes sorry, thanks tfor the clearer, i can edit my comment to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function display() {
var i = 0;
var str="YourString";
var temp = str.split("");
var reversestr = temp.reverse();

for (var i = 0, len = reversestr .length; i < len; i++) {
  document.write(reversestr [i] + "<br />");
}
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My Vertical Display</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="display()">
Click me to display.</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.blubb');
var stringToArray = element.innerHTML.split('');
var reveresedArray = stringToArray.reverse();

element.innerHTML = '';  // empty contents from .blubb
reveresedArray.forEach(function(letter){
    element.innerHTML += '<p>' + letter + '</p>';  // add letter with <p> tag
});
```

```html
<div class="blubb">Ineedtodisplay</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

write it from top to bottom but reverting it first

```
document.write(str.split('').reverse().join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var str = "ineedtodisplay";
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = str.split('').join('<br/>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## JS + CSS solution:

```js
// reverse the element's string order
var elm = document.querySelector('p');
elm.textContent = elm.textContent.split("").reverse().join("");
```

```css
p{
  font: 20px monospace; /* monospace fonts are best since each character has the same width */
  width: 20px; /* same as font-size */
  word-break: break-all; /* enabling the non-spaced text to break */
}
```

```html
<p>TEXT GOES FROM BOTTOM</p>
```